# AutoHotkey commands with Windows key stopped working in elevated programs

Tags: autohotkey

I've gotten a new laptop (with a newer version of Windows 10), and many AutoHotkey commands I had set up are not working the same. Specifically, some commands involving the Windows Key <kbd>⊞</kbd> in applications run as an administrator are working, and some are not.

```
^#!v::MsgBox testing ; Ctrl + Windows + Shift + v  Works everywhere
^#v::MsgBox testing  ; Ctrl + Windows + v          Does not work in admin windows
#v::MsgBox testing   ; Windows + v                 Does not in admin (opens clipboard mgr)

^#![::MsgBox testing ; Ctrl + Windows + Shift + [  Works everywhere
^#[::MsgBox testing  ; Ctrl + Windows + [          Works everywhere
#[::MsgBox testing   ; Windows + [                 Works everywhere
```

<kbd>⊞</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> works in admin windows. <kbd>⊞</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> does not. <kbd>⊞</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> does not.

I'm not running AutoHotkey as an administrator. All these commands worked without problem in admin windows on my previous laptop, so I am assuming it is a Windows 10 update issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain why your hotkeys worked on your previous laptop.

> By default, UAC protects "elevated" programs (that is, programs which are running as admin) from being automated by non-elevated programs, since that would allow them to bypass security restrictions. Hotkeys are also blocked, so for instance, a non-elevated program cannot spy on input intended for an elevated program.

https://autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#uac

https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=21278

Perhaps the UAC was disabled or set to a more permissive setting. Perhaps it really is a Windows 10 update issue as you suggest. If you are unwilling to run your script as an administrator, you could disable the UAC, though this is generally not recommended.

Comment: I am worried I have done something like mess with UAC settings on the old laptop that I've forgotten about. I'll play around with it for a while. It's nice when everything just works how it is supposed to! (Or at least, how my fingers remember that it should) 

Comment: Using the [AHK instructions](https://autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#uac) to run the script with the UIA exe `"AutoHotkeyU32_UIA.exe" "Your script.ahk"` did the trick. I must have set some Local Security Policy on the old laptop, but the company has disabled it on the new one.